# How to prevent sql injection both from client and server side?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

My approach to avoid sql injection::Html form

```
<form method="post" action="" style="padding:0;">
 <p> <span class="cclogin-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x fa-spin"></i></span>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" placeholder="First Name">
 </p>
  <p>
  <p> <span class="cclogin-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x fa-spin"></i></span>
   <input type="text" name="Email" value="" placeholder="Your Email">
 </p>
  <p>
  <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Submit">
  </p>
 </form>
```

Using ajax I am submitting my form and I also implemented captcha to my   form.
    On the action file, followed is the code which save data to database as :

```
   if(isset($_POST['Login'])&& ( $_POST['Login'] )) // submit button name
   {
     if($_POST['type_code']==$_SESSION['vercode']) // checking captcha code
    {
      $firstname = strip_tags($_POST['firstname']);
      $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
      $phone = $_POST['phone'];
      $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (firstname,email,phone)
      VALUES ('".$firstname."', '".$email."','".$phone.")";
      if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
         echo ‘records save successfully’;
       }
      Else
      {
         Echo ‘not saved data’;
       }
```

But after cross-site scripting scan I got lots of sql injection bugs 
             For example ::
                URL encoded POST input firstname was set to ttqevjod" onmouseover=prompt(949671)

The input is reflected inside a tag parameter between double quotes.
    To avoid such bugs my second approach was to restrict user from entering escape sequence characters into text field

This is as follow::
    1.  Check on key press event

```
     function blockSpecialChar(id)
      {
          var spclChars = "!@#$%^&*,\'\"(;:?.|-_)<>&[]{}+=`\/";
           var content =  $('#'+id).val(); 

                   for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) 
                       { 
                            if (spclChars.indexOf(content.charAt(i)) != -1) 
                            { 
                               alert ("Special characters are not allowed."); 
                                $('#'+id).val(''); 
                                return false; 
                           } 
                       } 
                }
   While saving data
     if(isset($_POST['Login'])&& ( $_POST['Login'] )) // submit button name
           {
               if($_POST['type_code']==$_SESSION['vercode']) // checking     captcha code
               {
     $firstname = htmlspecialchars ($_POST['firstname']);
     $email = htmlspecialchars ($_POST['email']);
     $phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']);
     $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (firstname,email,phone)
      VALUES ('".$firstname."', '".$email."','".$phone.")";
     if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo ‘records save successfully’;
     }
    Else
    {
       Echo ‘not saved data’;   
    }
```

But my supervisor said this is wrong method of preventing  sql   injection. Please guide me right way of preventing sql injection.

Comment: Don't concatenate your variables into `SQL` queries, use prepared statements.

Comment: I don't understand why people always come up with these "approaches" to prevent SQL injection. Every database library under the sun must offer parameterized queries (bind variables) these days. And these are usually easier to use than concatenating SQL strings anyway.

Comment: FWIW, you cannot prevent SQL injection client-side (because the attacker can make their own client)

Comment: thanks thilo for giving me this statement that 'sql injection cannot be prevented from client side'.